# Re-enable iPhone Simulator location services

Tags: ios-simulator, core-location

I have disabled location services on the simulator with the "Don't ask again" option set, thinking that I could re-enable it later, but now I can't find out how.

Can someone point me out where to change this setting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution:
System Preferences > Security > (Button) Reset Warnings

You may need to click the lock in the bottom left side before you can click that button.

Comment: Arrgh, no such button in Mac OS X Lion! :-o

Answer (score 3):

I did this and it worked: iOS Simulator > Reset Contents and Settings...
That deleted the apps installed in the simulator but also the settings for the GPS, well, and everything else.  I was able to reenable the gps after that.

Answer (score 2):

This setting is available in Lion under System Settings ... | Security & Privacy | Privacy (tab). However, I still have a problem with location services in the simulator even though it is enabled ....

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 12.2, I was able to find this by going to:
System Settings → General → Reset → Reset Location & Privacy`