# trigger.io - forge.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() not called

Tags: trigger.io

I use the toolkit trigger.io to develop my apps, now I need the current position of a user. Therefore, I'd like to use the forge.geolocation.getCurrentPosition method, unfortunately it does not work.
I call it in my pageinit event, like so:

```
 $(document).bind('pageinit',function(event){
 forge.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        alert("ok");    
      }, function(error) {
      alert("error");   
     });
 });
```

Unfortunately, I always get an error message.

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks,

enne

Comment: Could you change the error callback to include something like forge.logging.error(JSON.stringify(error)) so that we can see what the error is? I suspect you haven't got the module enabled... see your App Config tab.

Comment: well, it just says that "error" is undefined, the module is activated by the way.

Comment: Uups, ok, I found the message: Location services disabled ?!

Comment: Could it be that this function's not working on my ios-simulator?

Comment: Pretty sure you can set default locations in the simulator to override Cupertion, CA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing is that getCurrentPosition() works on a real device, but not on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reset your locations services since from your comment above it looks like you've disabled it at some point. This thread will help:

[Re-enable iPhone Simulator location services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337569/re-enable-iphone-simulator-location-services)

Comment: Well, I tried that but it still doesn't work. I guess it just don't work on the emulator, we will see how this is going to work on a real iPhone...